# How to obtain a sort of "spherical fall-off" displacement?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, volumetrics

I created two node trees that extrude a profile (a mesh made up of a few vertices, transformed into a curve, and to which a fillet is then applied to round the corners).

They extrude it in such a way as to create a three-dimensional effect whereby the farther from the contour of the profile, the higher the elevation of the points within the shape.

The red scooter in the figure uses a node based on volume. It creates a pleasant "spherical" shape, but the topology leaves something to be desired because it is a volume converted to mesh, so it is approximate.

[image: The red scooter use volume]

The green scooter, on the other hand, is created by intersecting the profile with a grid, then the position of the points on the grid is altered based on their distance from the edge. But in this case, the appearance is angular because the distance increases linearly.

[image: The green scooter use a grid displaced by distance from the edge]

I would like to be able to obtain the soft shape obtained in the red scooter, by modifying the node that generates the green scooter and make a sort of "rounder fall-of". I imagine there is a mathematical function that allows this and an associated node, but I do not know what they are. How can I do it?

Please see the example file

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I continue searching for an answer. Through experimentation, I discovered that using the Math node with the square root operation (and multiplying by a factor to regain the lost height) enables me to create a rounder/fatter displacement. Observe the right side of the green scooter in comparison to the left side on the screenshot below. It is undeniably smoother, but it is still not sufficient. A method to better control the roundness would be advantageous. I have experimented with Map Range and Color Ramp in various configurations, but something seems to elude me.. There must be a better way. Please help.

[image: using square root for fattening]

**Another update**

Using Robin Betts kind suggestion I tried to use Blur Attribute node. Result is interesting but still far from the red scooter shape.

[image: using blur attribute for fattening]

Comment: Might a _Blur_ of position help, somewhere along the line? It's a bit of a fuzzy method, too, though..

Comment: @RobinBetts please see my updated question. I tried your suggestion